# The Dirichlet Eta Function and the limits interchange

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, analysis, elementary-number-theory

**1-)** Let us handle the Dirichlet Eta Function and its partial sumshere which is convergent in the region
$0<\sigma< 1$  with  $s= \sigma +it $

$$ \eta (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}},  \text{  and...... }\eta_N (s)=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}} $$

Meanwhile, we have already known that:
$$\eta (s_0)=0 ⇔ \eta (1-s_0)=0$$

.

***Can we interchange the following limits?  If yes, how we can prove it ?***
$$ \tag{1}\lim_{s\to s_0}\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\lim_{s\to s_0}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{s}} $$

---

**2-)** Let us suppose we have the following equality in the region
$0<\sigma< 1$

$$\tag{2}\lim_{s\to s_0}\frac {\lim_{N\to \infty}\eta_N (s)}{\lim_{N\to \infty} \eta_N (1-s)}=h(s_0)$$
$h(s)$ is continuous and finite and non-zero in the region
$0<\sigma< 1$

***Thus, can we write the following equality depending on equation (2)? If yes, how we can prove it ?***

$$\tag{3}\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac {\eta_N (s_0)}{ \eta_N  (1-s_0)}=h(s_0)$$

Comment: See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition) on the Moore-Osgood Theorem, which provides a sufficient condition for interchanging the order of iterated limits.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119890/the-limit-on-the-ratio-of-the-dirichlet-eta-functions

Answer (score 2):

For $\Re(s) > 0$

$$|\eta(s)-\eta_{2N}(s)| = |\sum_{n=N}^\infty (2n+1)^{-s}-(2n+2)^{-s}|=|\sum_{n=N}^\infty \int_{2n+1}^{2n+2} s x^{-s-1}dx|\\\le |s|\sum_{n=N}^\infty \int_{2n}^{2n+2} x^{-\Re(s)-1}dx=|s|\frac{(2N)^{-\Re(s)}}{\Re(s)}$$
(this proves $\eta(s)$ is well-defined, continuous, analytic, bounded by $|s|/\Re(s)$)

If $\eta(s)\ne 0$ and $\Re(s)\in (0,1)$ then $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\eta_N(s)}{\eta_N(1-s)} = \frac{\eta(s)}{\eta(1-s)}$$

If $\eta(s)=0$ it is different : $$|\eta(s)-\eta_{2N}(s)-\frac12 (2N+1)^{-s}|\\ = |\sum_{n=N}^\infty \int_0^1 s((2n+x+1)^{-s-1}-(2n+2x+1)^{-s-1})dx|\\=
 |\sum_{n=N}^\infty \int_0^1 s\int_x^{2x} (s+1)(2n+t+1)^{-s-2}dtdx|\le \frac{|s(s+1)| (2N+1)^{-\Re(s)-1}}{\Re(s+1)}$$
thus for $\eta(s)=0,\Re(s) \in (1/2,1)$ $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\eta_N(s)}{\eta_N(1-s)} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\frac12(2N+1)^{-s}}{\frac12 (2N+1)^{s-1}}=0$$

Comment: Dear Reuns, thank you. let us go on step by step.  Can we interchange the limits in my first question?

Comment: That's what the bound I gave is useful for. You should start by using it to show $\eta(s)$ is continuous, from $|\eta(s)-\eta(s_2)| \le |\eta_N(s)-\eta_N(s_2)|+|\eta(s)-\eta_N(s)|+|\eta(s_2)-\eta_N(s_2)|$

Comment: Thank you , it mean,  Yes ? Please then I will pass my second comment

Comment: You are asking if $\lim_{s \to s_0} \eta(s)=  \lim_{N \to \infty} \eta_N(s_0)$ this is the convergence of $\eta_N$ and the continuity of $\eta$. The continuity follows from that $\eta_N$ is continuous and the uniform convergence (see my comment above)

Comment: Yes, I am asking this one. Okay I understand now , we can do these limit interchanges. Thank you. Please see my reply , I wrote it to you.

Comment: Do you see how $\eta_{2N}'(s)= -\sum_{n=1}^N s\int_{2n-1}^{2n} \log (x) x^{-s-1}dx$  gives $|\eta_N'(s)| \le |s|\int_1^\infty \log(x)x^{-\Re(s)-1}dx = \frac{|s|}{\Re(s)^2}$ from which $|\eta_N(s)-\eta_N(s_0)|\le \frac{|s-s_0| }{\min(\Re(s_0),\Re(s))^2}$ and $\eta(s)-\eta(s_0)|\le \frac{|s-s_0| }{\min(\Re(s_0),\Re(s))^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

@reuns, you wrote as:

If $\eta(s)\ne 0$ and $\Re(s)\in (0,1)$ then $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{\eta_N(s)}{\eta_N(1-s)} = \frac{\eta(s)}{\eta(1-s)}=h(s)$$

Thus now, let us consider some $s$ which very near $s_0$ as $ε$ sufficiently small as $0<ε$  as below:

$$s_0^-=(σ_0-ε)+it_0 \text{  and} ......s_0^+=(σ_0+ε)+it_0$$

$$\tag{4}\lim_{s\to s_0^-}\frac {\lim_{N\to \infty}\eta_N (s)}{\lim_{N\to \infty} \eta_N (1-s)}=h(s_0^-)$$

$$\tag{5}\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac {\eta_N (s_0^-)}{ \eta_N  (1-s_0^-)}=h(s_0^-)$$

We could write it also with $s_0^+=(σ_0+ε)+it_0$

Anyway now, we can see easly the follwing one by  $\lim {ε\to 0}$.

$$h(s_0^-)=h(s_0^+)=h(s_0)$$

Because   $h(s)$ is continuous and finite and non-zero in the region 
$0<\sigma< 1$

Thus, can we write the following one depending **equation (4)** ? According to me YES !!.

$$\tag{6}\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac {\eta_N (s_0)}{ \eta_N  (1-s_0)}=h(s_0)$$

Comment: @reuns, can I take your last comment? Just as your final comment.

Comment: equation $6$ is incorrect as you cannot switch limits here since you have division by zero; it's easy to give counterexamples using the Davenport Heilbronn function $f$, for example which has the same properties as one used for $\eta$ ($f(s)=0$ iff $f(1-s)=0$, $\frac{f(s)}{f(1-s)}=h(s), h(s) \ne 0, 0< \Re s <1$, $f$ uniformly approximated by its finite Dirichlet sum as it is a linear combination of two $L$ functions of non-principal characters modulo $5$ and $f$ has tons of zeros in the critical strip but not on the line $\Re s =.5$ for which equation 6 above is just demonstrably false

Comment: @Conrad, thank you.  I think we can write easily, without any problem,  YES ?:    $$\tag{7}\lim_{s\to s_0}\frac {\eta (s)}{ \eta  (1-s)}=h(s_0)$$

Comment: No we cannot since LHS limit is zero, RHS is non-zero